# help figuring out math formula for performance gains

Tags: sql, math

I'm trying to write a report to recommend moving transaction logs to a separate physical drive but I need to provide some numbers. I have some queries from a profile that was done last month. I'm trying to determine the reduction % of the duration. I know that it can't be 100% exact but a very close numbert will suffice.

Query 1
Reads: 325229284
Writes: 85989
Duration: 840732

Query 2
Reads: 558955611
Writes: 87066
Duration: 1015697

Query 3
Reads: 422966141
Writes: 85087
Duration: 918225

currently reads and writes happen on the same drive. I want to move them so reads are one drive and writes are another. I tried to figure it out assuming writes are 20% slower than reads but didn't average in seek times. I was getting between 7%-15% but have no idea if those figures are correct. Assuming drive seek time is avg 1ms.

Comment: Don't assume. Mirror the system as closely as you can and do actual testing. It's harder to refute facts than assumptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thoughts:

- The read/write correlation is usually nothing to do with logs. It's sorting in tempdb, spools etc.
- You'd need one extra volume per database LDF: otherwise you still have massive head movement and many databases write to one volume
- If you aren't using a SAN, then to do this you'll have less disks per volumes.
- What could be beneficial is moving tempdb to separate volumes. SQL Server 2005+ really spank tempdb compared to older versions (eg triggers use tempdb rather than the logs)
- MDF/LDF split is often for recovery: you can back up the tail of the log if the data volume fails
- If a query has 422,966,141 reads then fix your code and indexes. A separate log drive is re-arranging deck chairs on the titanic.

Comment: I agree but with 350gb database and 195gb log file and everything running from a single drive, i'm trying to get them to separate logs, tempdb and indexes to separate drives as well as archiving historical data. Query optimization wont help all that much at this point. This is just the start.